# Improve speed of "sshuttle" with multiple connections?

Tags: ssh, vpn, subnet

In the [sshuttle documentation](http://sshuttle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manpage.html): "It’s valid to run sshuttle more than once simultaneously on a single client machine, connecting to a different server every time, so you can be on more than one VPN at once."

That sounded great because sshuttle is slow and I was thinking this could double my speed, but I can't find any examples of how to do this. By "every time" I was thinking half my data would go through the 1st vpn and the other half through the 2nd vpn. I'm not a subnet genius and can't figure it out.

I did find "[sshoot](https://github.com/albertodonato/sshoot)" which is a way to use sshuttle to run vpn1 and vpn2 at the same time, but if they are both configured with "0/0" it seems vpn2 handles all the traffic, rendering vpn1 useless.

Basically, I want to route half of everything (more or less) through vpn1, and the other half through vpn2. This is only for fun and doesn't need to be perfect. Sshuttle seems to allow subnet ranges, but I don't know what ranges I would use to capture "half of everything."